# How to disable WinMain entry point for a MFC application?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, entry-point, winmain

I understand that is not possible to have applications with multiple entry points under Windows.

I have a MFC application and I added code for making it running as a service (`main()` entry point and other required stuff) but it looks that Windows will always run the `WinMain()` from MFC instead of my main.

The question is how can I disable the `WinMain()` from MFC in order to be able to run my own `main()`.

Probably the same problem would apply if you want to run the same application as a console application.

What do I have to change in project properties in order to build it as a console application (main instead of WinMain)?

Is commenting my CWinApp the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the linker settings you can change the entry point.  This is where you want to be looking.

Comment: I was looking before writing but now I found the option: `Linker > System > SubSystem`